# Planet gravity?

Tags: phaser

I am trying to make a game with the [Phaser game engine](http://phaser.io/) and would like to implement some sort of planetary gravity. Essentially I just want the player to be able to walk on a circle or orbit a point. I was wondering what would be the best way to do this in phaser. I know that you can set objects gravities but you can only do so in the x and y direction.

Comment: What's "360-degree gravity"? Do you mean [Newton's law of universal gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation)?

Comment: No I want the player to be able to walk along a circular planet but phaser only allows you to apply gravity in one particular y direction and one particular x direction.

Comment: Not sure but you could probably deduce the gravity direction from the normals of your mesh.

Comment: Try communicating what you mean more clearly. You probably have a nice picture in your mind's eye of exactly what you're talking about but you have not done a good job of conveying it to us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phaser doesn't have built-in support for any fancier gravity, so you'll have to roll your own. Fortunately it's fairly easy to understand, so you just calculate your own gravity in the game's `update()` function, which is simply a (properly scaled) vector from your player to the planet's center of gravity, and set your player's `body.gravity` property, or you can manually add the gravity vector to the `body.velocity` property.

Here's an example of the first approach: http://jsfiddle.net/gJ4kA/

```
function create() {

    planet = game.add.sprite(200, 150, 'planet');

    ship = game.add.sprite(200, 32, 'ship');
    // Use our own gravity
    ship.body.allowGravity = false;
    // Set an initial motion
    ship.body.velocity.x = 100;

}

function update() {

    // Calculate gravity as the normalised vector from the ship to the planet
    ship.body.gravity = new Phaser.Point(planet.body.x - ship.body.x, planet.body.y - ship.body.y);
    // Normalize and multiply by actual strength of gravity desired
    ship.body.gravity = ship.body.gravity.normalize().multiply(300, 300);

}
```

This is probably not accurate enough if you're making a simulation, but for simple games it is fine.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer I was looking for I appreciate the help!

Comment: Is there any way to only have the gravity be multiplied once, right now it is being multiplied every time update is called resulting in increasing gravity. Thanks!